# BASH: count # of words in each line of a document

Tags: bash, patterns

I need to identify patterns in a text file for further analysis. So the input files may contain semi-structured text as follows;

**file1**

```
905:john: abc123: john@doe.com: US  
920:eric: ericaA: eric007@gmail.com: US  
1000: rio: ri0ri0: rio@yahoo.com: IN
```

**file2**

```
nathen <tab> nathen@yman.com <tab> 764323545 <tab> UK
thomas <tab> thom@gmail.com <tab> 563363421 <tab> UK
ian <tab> rt@gmail.com <tab> 3453245472 <tab> SP
```

number of words in a line may vary for each document. delimiter also vary but unique for each document. what I want is to count number of words per each line in each document.

output would be:

*for file1*

```
5  
5 
5 
5
```

*for file2*

```
4  
4 
4 
4
```

I want generalize this for any file with any delimiter.  It could be `- | : \space+ \tab+`.

Some files are as follows:

```
| hetro@gmail.com | er34532 |  
| rt@gmail.com | 764474 |
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For file2 with its simple format of white-space separated words, try:

```
$ awk '{print NF}' file2
4
4
4
```

In awk, `NF` is the number of fields.  In awk by default, words characters separated by white-space.

For file1, for which words may be separated by colons or spaces, we need to add `:` to the field separator:

```
$ awk -F'[: \t]+' '{print NF}' file1
5
5
5
```

#### Improvement

awk will think there are extra fields if a line has leading or trailing whitespace.  We can fix that by removing any such whitespace before we count the fields, like this for file1:

```
awk -F'[: \t]+' '{gsub(/^[: \t]+|[: \t]+$/, ""); print NF}' file1
```

or this for file2:

```
awk '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/, ""); print NF}' file2
```

In the regex, `^[[:space:]]+` matches leading whitespace and `[[:space:]]+$` matches trailing whitespace.  Their combination in the `gsub` command removes  both.

#### Generalization

If the field separator could be any of - | :  or , then use:

```
awk -F'[-|: \t]+' '{gsub(/^[[-\|: \t]+|[[-\|: \t]+$/, ""); print NF}'
```

Example:

```
$ cat file3
| hetro@gmail.com | er34532 |  
| rt@gmail.com | 764474 |
$ awk -F'[-|: \t]+' '{gsub(/^[[-\|: \t]+|[[-\|: \t]+$/, ""); print NF}' file3
2
2
```

Comment: Very informative. Thanks. Please see my reply also

Comment: @user3148655 Your welcome.  Also, I added code that handles all those possible delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1849415/4440445) in perl to count substrings matching a word regex of your choosing e.g. to count sequences of "words" consisting of perl's `\w` character set augmented with `@` and `.`

```
perl -lne 'print my $count = () = $_ =~ /[\w@.]+/g' somefile
```

which gives

```
$ perl -lne 'print my $count = () = $_ =~ /[\w@.]+/g' file1
5
5
5
```

and

```
$ perl -lne 'print my $count = () = $_ =~ /[\w@.]+/g' file2
4
4
4
```

for your sample files.